# Navigating up the visual tree in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have an image being displayed in a DataTemplate. I want to change the style of the DataTemplate that's surrounding my image when the image is clicked on.

It used to be nested directly in a stackpanel like the following so I could get the parent stackpanel easily by doing the following.

```
StackPanel sp = img.Parent as StackPanel;
```

```
<StackPanel Name="uxSessionImageItem" Style="{DynamicResource RotatorItemTemplateUnselectedStyle}" Loaded="uxSessionImageItem_Loaded" >
     <TextBlock Name="uxLabel"  Width="150" Text="{Binding SessionImageID}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     <Image MouseDown="ImagePanel_MouseDown" Name="uxImage" Style="{DynamicResource ItemTemplateImageStyle}" Source="{Binding ThumbPath}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I had to add another stackpanel and a border in between the image and the stack panel that I need to find. What syntax do I need to find not the border that is now my parent nor the stackpanel that's the border's parent but the stackpanel above that one?

```
<StackPanel Name="uxSessionImageItem" Style="{DynamicResource RotatorItemTemplateUnselectedStyle}" Loaded="uxSessionImageItem_Loaded" >
    <TextBlock Name="uxLabel"  Width="150" Text="{Binding SessionImageID}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ItemTemplateImageNumberStyle}"/>
    <StackPanel Name="uxSessionImageWrapper" Style="{DynamicResource RotatorItemImageWrapperStyle}" >
        <Border Name="uxImageBorder" Style="{DynamicResource ItemTemplateImageBorderStyle}">
            <Image MouseDown="ImagePanel_MouseDown" Name="uxImage" Style="{DynamicResource ItemTemplateImageStyle}" Source="{Binding ThumbPath}"/>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 14):

CodeNaked answer is good, but i don't like the fact that the code in that article use recursion to accomplish this simple task, so here's a modified version, which can possibly avoid a stack overflow (not sure WPF can be nested so much, but is it worth risking ?)

```
public static T FindParentOfType<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject parentDepObj = child;
    do
    {
        parentDepObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parentDepObj);
        T parent = parentDepObj as T;
        if (parent != null) return parent;
    }
    while (parentDepObj != null);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to navigate up or down the visual tree. The [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent.aspx) property is the logical parent, which is different. This is explained more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx).

You can use this [Linq To Visual Tree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) code to use Linq type statements to traverse the visual tree, but this ultimately leverage the VisualTreeHelper class. Or you can build extension methods like [this one](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent) to make finding ancestors (not necessarily direct parents) easier.

Answer (score 0):

`img.Parent.Parent.Parent` is the outer StackPanel.

(The fact that there are multiple elements at the same level in a StackPanel is only a problem if you go down the VisualTree, up is always easy as every element can only have one parent.)

**Edit:** As CodeNaked pointed out `Parent` uses the logical tree, this should not be a problem if all you look for is a relative reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand that if you already named your StackPanel `uxSessionImageItem`, why don't you use it to reference it in your code?

Comment: If it's in a DataTemplate then you can't access by name via code-behind like that. There could be several instances of the StackPanel for each time the DataTemplate is used.

Comment: Thx, missed the DataTemplate part.