# Set Focus on parent TabItem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, setfocus

Is there a way to automatically switch to a TabItem that hosts a control I want to focus?

My sample window to exemplify the issue.

```xml
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Background="White">
            <TabItem Header="TabItem1">
                <Button x:Name="SomeButton" Content="Set Focus on TextBox" Width="120" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem2">
                <TextBox x:Name="SomeTextBox" Margin="10" Text="Sample text"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
            <Button Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeTextBox.Focus();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

So, when clicking `SomeButton`, I want to move the focus to `SomeTextBox` but, for that to work, I have to select `TabItem2` first. That's obviously easy in the provided example, but I'm looking for an automated solution that 'knows' that `SomeTextBox` belongs to `TabItem2` and switches to it and then sets the focus on the desired control. Needless to say that in the real case scenario `SomeTextBox` might be in some other level in the `VisualTree` in some other kind of pane. Is it possible?

BTW, if it helps, the application of such feature would be setting the focus on a control highlighted by error validation and/or switching to the pane that holds it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) class to find the nearest parent of a specific type.

Here's an implementation example from [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41985834/14956277).

```
public static T FindParentOfType<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject parentDepObj = child;
    do
    {
        parentDepObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parentDepObj);
        T parent = parentDepObj as T;
        if (parent != null) return parent;
    }
    while (parentDepObj != null);
    return null;
}
```

Once you have a reference to your `TabItem`, you can set its [`IsSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabitem.isselected?view=net-5.0) property to select it in the `TabControl`.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tabItem = FindParentOfType<TabItem>(SomeTextBox);
    if (tabItem is null) return;
    (tabItem as TabItem).IsSelected = true;
    SomeTextBox.Focus();
}
```

**Edit**

Good catch on the `TextBox` not being in the visual tree while its parent `TabItem` is not selected. Here's another way to get at the `TextBox` that isn't dependent on the visual tree.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement currentItem = SomeTextBox;
    do
    {
        currentItem = (FrameworkElement)currentItem.Parent;
    }
    while (!(currentItem is TabItem)
           && (currentItem as TabItem).Parent != MyTabControl // Optional handling in case you have nested TabControls
           && !(currentItem.Parent is null));

    (currentItem as TabItem).IsSelected = true;
    currentItem.UpdateLayout();
        
    SomeTextBox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dakota but that didn't worked. My best guess is that SomeTextBox is removed from the VisualTree when the parent TabItem isn't selected.

Comment: Good catch, I added another approach at the bottom of the answer. It's more error prone, so be careful if you start getting complex layouts.

Comment: Only one tiny detail left: after selecting the parent container, an UpdateLayout is required, otherwise the Focus won't work. Please add it for other users. Thank you for the heads up on complex layouts, I'll adjust to my needs. I'm gonna put this in my ViewFactory and look for containers that somehow need selection. Great work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As a footnote, one could use the LogicalTreeHelper instead of the VisualTreeHelp.